# WordPress permalinks are not working

Tags: linux, php, wordpress

I am having a problem with WordPress permalink redirects not working correctly.
I was able to specify the permalink convension through settings interface. WordPress properly names hyperlink. However, when redirects return requested URL not found on this server. Turning back to default does not either. Clicking on my_url/?p=123 redirects me to the last selected permalink convention such as my_url/%postname%/ which in turn results in Not Found error. I checked and my .htaccess is writable and it has the below inside:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

How can I delete those stale redirects?

Thank you

Comment: For some reason, adding an option +FollowSymlinks to .htaccess solves the problem with Default Settings not working. However, other options such as site/%postname%/ still do not work. Please advise!

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured the problem out.
My /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf had AllowOverride set to None. Once I allowed overrides for my directory, .htaccess started affecting the configuration. Now, permalinks work as they should.